# Changing a list value using a list comprehension in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have a nested list made up of 'x's and '.'s, with the boundaries represented by '-'. If there is a 'x', I have to change the '.' within the 3x3 square of the 'x' to a character such as '|'.

I have working code, but I am wondering if and how I could use list comprehension on this problem instead? I don't know how or if I can replace a value in my nested list using list comprehension. I only that when using list comprehension like

```
myList = [expression, for clause, condition]
```

the code adds the expression to myList as it iterates through the for loop and checks the condition.

Given this as my original list:

```
myList = [
         ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
         ['-','x','.','.','-','-','-'],
         ['-','.','.','.','-','-','-'],
         ['-','.','x','.','-','-','-'],
         ['-','.','.','.','.','.','-'],
         ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
         ]
```

I have to change it to this (assuming the initial row and column are 3 and 2:

```
myList = [
         ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],
         ['-','x','.','.','-','-','-'],
         ['-','|','|','|','-','-','-'],
         ['-','|','x','|','-','-','-'],
         ['-','|','|','|','.','.','-'],
         ['-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
         ]
```

My function takes a nested list and the row and column values of the 'x' as input parameters. Here is what I have and this works:

```
for row in [y-1, y, y+1]:
    for column in [x-1, x, x+1]:
        if nestedList[row][column] == '.':
            nestedList[row][column] = character
```

Comment: Comprehensions are not designed to modify items in relation to other items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best idea but here's the answer:

```
x = 2
y = 3
[['|' if x-1 <= i <= x+1 and y-1 <= j <= y+1 and (myList[j][i] == '.') else myList[j][i] for i in range(len(myList[y]))] for j in range(len(myList))]
```

Note that this generates a new list because list comprehension does not work with assignments. Here's expanded for clarity:

```
[['|' if x-1 <= i <= x+1 and y-1 <= j <= y+1\
  and (myList[j][i] == '.') else myList[j][i]\
  for i in range(len(myList[y]))] for j in range(len(myList))]
```